# is there a reason why the len function displays the wrong lengh of a word (no spaces etc.)?

Tags: import, output, character, string-length

following scenario: I want to display the length of a random word selected from a simple .txt list like this:

```
composer
circulation
fashionable
prejudice
progress
salesperson
disappoint
```

I used the following code to display one of these words from the list:

```
random_word_generator = open("random_words.txt", "r")
random_words = list(random_word_generator)
secret_word = random.choice(random_words)
```

however, whenever I want to print the length of the word by using:

```
print("My secret word is " + str(len(secret_word)))
```

It shows the length of the word - 1 character

like:

progress --> should be 8 letters, but python displays 7...

Do you know how this issue could be solved?

Btw: there are no spaces whatsoever in my .txt file

Kind Regards and many thanks in advance

Comment: you are not reading your file content

Comment: To my knowledge I am. When I print the secret_word it displays a random word from the .txt file

Comment: yes my bad, you read it but this is not the pythonic way to read. use `with` and `strip` to get read of the end of line

Comment: could you show how you'd modify the code displayed above with "with" and "strip"? I am just curious, although anonymus1994.1's solution already worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mention the language you're using in the title and the tags.

To your question: Can you please paste the full code you're using? I tried your example, and it displays the correct length of each word (+ 1 for the newline character, which you could remove by calling `.strip()`), so I'm guessing you do something different.

```py
random_word_generator = open("random_words.txt", "r")
random_words = list(random_word_generator) # ['composer\n', 'circulation\n', 'fashionable\n', 'prejudice\n', 'progress\n', 'salesperson\n', 'disappoint\n']
secret_word = random.choice(random_words) # "progress\n"
print("My secret word is " + str(len(secret_word))) # "My secret word is 9"
print("My secret word w/o newline is " + str(len(secret_word.strip()))) # "My secret word w/o newline is 8"
```

Comment: first of all: you are totally right, should have mentioned the language as well... I am new here - next time I will do better

Secondly: Thanks! It's working now. .strip() was the solution!